# PHPExcel - How to calculate a value based on the data from an excel sheet without using setCellValue() to insert a formula in the first place?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I did a lot of research but couldn't really find an answer to this.

I used PHPExcel for reading raw data from an excel sheet. It works fine.  Now I need to get a SUM from cell `A1` to `A500`, i.e. `SUM(A1:A500)`. To do that, I understand I need to:

- Step 1. Insert this formula to a cell using
  `$sheet1->setCellValue(B1, "=SUM(A1:A500)")`.
- Step 2. Use `$sum = $sheet1->getCell('B1')->getCalculatedValue()` to get the calculated value.

My question is, is there any way to get the $sum without the need of inserting the formula into a cell in the first place? In other words, to achieve the result in Step 2 without Step 1. Because I don't want to add/change/edit anything onto the original excel sheet.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just run some tests with this.

While you don't need to read a cell containing the formula... you can just execute the formula itself using the calculation engine... but you do still need to pass a cell reference (can be any cell in the worksheet; I've used A1 here, because A1 should always exist) to the calculation engine:

(assuming that `$objPHPExcel` is the PHPExcel object that you've loaded from file)

```
$formula = '=SUM(A1:A500)';
$sum = PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance(
    $objPHPExcel
)->calculateFormula($formula, 'A1', $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1'));
```

or using your `$sheet1` directly

```
$formula = '=SUM(A1:A500)';
$sum = PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance(
    $sheet1->getParent()
)->calculateFormula($formula, 'A1', $sheet1->getCell('A1'));
```

Comment: That answered my question. It was indeed exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you very much for your help, Mark.

Comment: Hi Mark.  I have tried your suggested methods, but I got this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function getCoordinate() on a non-object in ...\PHPExcel\Calculation.php on line 3150"

Comment: You may need to specify the worksheet name in your formula: `$formula = '=SUM('Worksheet 1'!A1:A500)';`

Comment: I did that, somehow still have the same error.  Below is my codes.

Comment: I'll make some mods to the next release of PHPExcel so that it will set some default values for the cell address and cell object if it's running against a PHPExcel instance, but it'll work for now if they're passed manually

Comment: That will be great.  PHPExcel has been a very useful tool.  Looking forwards for the next release. :-)